# Is enabling CDI mandatory in JSF 2.3

Tags: java, jsf

I am trying to upgrade a project from JSF 1.1 to JSF 2.3. The project uses JSP and runs on Tomcat 9.

The specific JSF dependency I have added in my build.gradle is as below:

```
api 'org.glassfish:javax.faces:2.3.9'
```

To begin with I want to do minimal changes to the project and thus I want my faces-config.xml to still work and my managed-beans to be managed by JSF and not CDI. I also do not want PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING for now.

So I added the following params to my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.ENABLE_CDI_RESOLVER_CHAIN</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

However, when I start tomcat, I still get the following error:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager
at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.tryAddCDIELResolver(ELUtils.java:312)
at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.buildFacesResolver(ELUtils.java:242)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeELResolverChains(ApplicationAssociate.java:503)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.performOneTimeELInitialization(ApplicationImpl.java:1405)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.getELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:529)
```

Could someone please guide as to why this is not working? How can I de-activate/disable CDI in my project so that my beans continue to be JSF managed. Do I need to do something else along with making javax.faces.ENABLE_CDI_RESOLVER_CHAIN false?

Thanks!